# How to write linq query for sample xml

Tags: c#, linq

How to get the collection of values of elements from such an xml, using linq
(root/doc/files/file):

```
<root>

  <doc>
    <files>
      <file>1</file>
      <file>2</file>
      <file>3</file>    
    </files>   
  </doc>

  <doc>
    <files>
      <file>4</file>
      <file>5</file>
      <file>6</file>    
    </files>   
  </doc>

</root>
```

From that query I would like to have:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Here is the beginning of the code I have written so far.

```
    string xmlIn = "<root> "+
                   "   <doc>"+
                   "     <files>"+
                   "       <file>1</file>"+
                   "       <file>2</file>"+
                   "       <file>3</file>  "+  
                   "     </files>   "+
                   "   </doc>"+

                   " <doc>"+
                   "     <files>"+
                   "       <file>4</file>"+
                   "       <file>5</file>"+
                   "       <file>6</file>  "+  
                   "     </files>   "+
                   "   </doc>"+

                   " </root>";

    var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlin);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: Don't have even a sample, as I have no idea how to write it in linq.

Comment: Have a squiz at http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Descendants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var result= root.Descendants("file").Select(e=>e.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

C#/.NET has an XML deserializer/parser:

```
using System.Xml;
```

you can use it to load the XML:

```
  //using a previously created stream that holds an XML document
     XDocument xdoc =  XDocument.Load(xmlstream);
```

You can then use LINQ to select what you want:

```
 // this example looks for a tag called 'object' and then collects all
 // the objects of type 'cluster'
 var clusters = from cluster in _XDoc.Descendants("object")
                       where cluster.Attribute("type").Value == "cluster"
                       select cluster;
```